# How to get value which is been change with help of that i want to login

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In these code I am trying to submit the form with `username='admin'` and `password='password'` on submit it will go to edit page. If user want to change the `username` and `password` it can change here, but my question is what changes I've to make in my code so that it can read what changes where made, if any, in `username` and `password`, and proceeds with login.
    First time it should login with credentials as `admin and password` in future if user change then what I have to do

```
$(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {          
        $("#button").click(function () {
             callXMLConnection();
        });
        $("#button1").click(function () {
             callConnection();
        }); 
});

function callXMLConnection(){
    var u1 = $("#textusername").val();
    var p1 = $("#textpassword").val();
    if(u1 == 'admin' && p1 == 'password'){
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
        $("#textusername1").val(u1);
        $("#textpassword1").val(p1);
    }else{
        alert("username and password is not correct");
    }
}
function callConnection(){
    localStorage.setItem("user", $("#textusername1").val());
    localStorage.setItem("pass", $("#textpassword1").val());
    localStorage.setItem("auth", $("#textauthentication").val());
    if(localStorage.getItem("user") == "" && localStorage.getItem("pass") == ""){
        alert("enter the username and password");
    }else{
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the new credentials in localStorage, so during login check if they exist and retrieve them, if not then use the default values:

```
function callXMLConnection(){
    var u1 = $("#textusername").val();
    var p1 = $("#textpassword").val();

    //Check for stored credentials and use defaults if not found
    var user = localStorage.getItem("user") ? localStorage.getItem("user") : 'admin';
    var password = localStorage.getItem("password") ? localStorage.getItem("password") : 'password';

    if(u1 == user && p1 === password){ 
         $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
         $("#textusername1").val(u1);
         $("#textpassword1").val(p1);            
    }else{
      alert("username and password is not correct");
    }
}
```